# Github API: pull request by user

Tags: github, github-api

I'm wondering whether it's possible to use the github API to get a sense for the pull request frequency overtime by user (each contributor to my public project). How can you do this?

Comment: I doubt it will be a meaningful metric unless the PRs are normalized. Otherwise it's counting apples and oranges.